# how to fadeIn and fadeOut html()

Tags: jquery

i have this 23 jpeg images but i couldnt do the proper animation like fadein fadeout
heres my code:

```
var srcStr1 = "../img/portrait/anne/",
                srcStr2 = ".jpg",
                counter = 1,
                pos =0,
                x;

            var anne = $('#anne').attr('rel');

                if(typeof(anne) == "undefined" || anne.length < 1) {
                    x = 1;  
                } else if (anne < 23 && anne != 23) {
                    x = parseInt(anne) + 1; 
                } else {
                    x = 1;  
                }

            $('div').html('<img id="anne" src="' + srcStr1 + x + srcStr2 + '" rel="' + x + '"/>');
```

Comment: Where are you trying to `fade` anything in that example?

Comment: im fading the image what i did is icrementing the image attribute from 1to23 to change the image but it doesnt fade it just blinking,the images was got from a burst shot it like i want to put the together like a playing video with just a fadein fadeout effect if possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding, you want to change the src attribute of the image to simulate a fade effect. Using your existing code, you would have to add a timeout mechanism for the fade effect to work. Your code, as it is written, assuming it is in a loop and stops at 23, would just count to the highest possible value and then display the new image. Something like this should do the trick, causing each image to be displayed for roughly 100ms, making the total animation 2.3 seconds.

```
function fadeIn() {
    // your code here
    setTimeout(fadeIn,100);
}
```